# Spark inner join two RDD and new value should be a sum of the old values

Tags: python, apache-spark, inner-join, rdd

I have two RDD and I want to have a inner join, then the new value should be a sum of the values in `rdd1` and `rdd2`

An example:

```
RDD1 = [(key1,(1,2)), (key2,(2,3)),(key3,(3,4))]
RDD2 = [(key1,(2,3), (key3,(4,5))]

RDD_inner_join= [(key1,(3,5), (key3,(7,9))]
```

I have tried with `rdd1.join(rdd2)` but I suppose that we can't do any operation with the old value when we join the two `rdd`.

Does someone have an idea to solve my problem?

Comment: `join` is the good way, after joining you have access to RDD elements. Can you share your code with join so we can help you find bug inside?

Comment: thanks, I agree that join is a good way, but after join we have a tuple like this (key,(value1,value2)), but I need a tuple after join like (key, value+value2)

Answer (score 0):

After joining both RDDs perform map transformation like this:

```
joinedRDDs.map(lambda r: (r[0], r[1][0][0] + r[1][1][0], r[1][0][1] + r[1][1][1]))
```

And you will get expected results.

Comment: Thanks Mariusz, that would be a good idea if we do another job mapreduce after the join.

Comment: Actually, in spark there is not such thing like "mapreduce job". Your application will perform two transformations (shuffling join and non-shuffling map) and then some action (like saving results on storage, displaying it, etc). And that's OK, it's basically how you write applications in spark.